# Go - cannot compile hello world (Windows)

Tags: compilation, go

Just trying out Go, but I can't get it to compile my very first program. This caused a bunch of questions on the compiler.

It is contained in this single file:

```
"D:\programming\Go\src\mytest\mytest.go"
```

the program text is:

```
// mytest project mytest.go
package mytest

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, Go!")
}
```

In the package folder I tried the following commands:

```
>go build
```

says nothing. According to `go help build` this is the intended result.

```
>go build -v
_/D_/programming/Go/src/mytest
```

What are the `_/D_/` things are??? Looks like a new invention!

And the most strange one:

```
>go build -v mytest
can't load package: package mytest: import "mytest": cannot find package
```

So what am I doing wrong and how do I get the thing compiled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `main` function in a program must be in package `main`. Package `main` can then import other packages and call them.

Comment: Wow! Did not expect this these days... The `exe` of this program, came out in 1.2Mb. I think Go is yet in it's development stage, so I hope we will see better results later on.

Comment: The program size is reasonable and expected: Go FAQ. Why is my trivial program such a large binary? http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary.

Comment: @peterSO alright! Actually, a pretty widespread approach it is. I suppose this is for our benifit then :)

Comment: @peterSO, umm, wait, you said runtime? Is Go language interpreted? I can't seem to find papers on this..

Comment: @noncom No, it is not interpreted. It has a runtime, which is statically linked in. You'll see similar sizes if you statically link a C application - it brings in the CRT, C++ applications would bring in the CRT and the standard C++ library. Unless you are distributing your programs on floppy disks, this is not an issue. Really, it isn't.

Comment: @nos, yeah, today this is not a problem, just I wanted to ask and know)

Comment: @noncom Not always a problem. One of the top two reasons programmers choose Go over Python is because it's compiled (to native code) rather than interpreted.

Comment: don't think that I consider an interpreted language being a problem.. I come from Java land ahahah :D